# mobile App with ionic

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework

**hello**
I am trying to build hybrid app with ionic and cordova 
at first i run below commands and they run successfully
but after running the last command i get this error

```
ionic start firtApp

cd firtApp

ionic platform add android
```

note: it return me android-21 error, and i changed the android-21 to android-18, and it runs successfully

```
ionic build android
```

after running the above command i got this error

```
BUILD FAILED
D:\New folder\android-sdk-final\android-sdk-fully\sdk\tools\ant\build.xml:601: T
he following error occurred while executing this line:
D:\New folder\android-sdk-final\android-sdk-fully\sdk\tools\ant\build.xml:542: U
nable to resolve project target 'android-21'

Total time: 1 second

C:\Users\Mohammad\firstapp\platforms\android\cordova\node_modules\q\q.js:126
                    throw e;
                          ^
Error code 1 for command: cmd with args: /s /c "ant debug -f C:\Users\Mohammad\f
irstapp\platforms\android\build.xml -Dout.dir=ant-build -Dgen.absolute.dir=ant-g
en"
ERROR building one of the platforms: Error: C:\Users\Mohammad\firstapp\platforms
\android\cordova\build.bat: Command failed with exit code 8
You may not have the required environment or OS to build this project
Error: C:\Users\Mohammad\firstapp\platforms\android\cordova\build.bat: Command f
ailed with exit code 8
    at ChildProcess.whenDone (C:\Users\Mohammad\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules
\cordova\node_modules\cordova-lib\src\cordova\superspawn.js:131:23)
    at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:98:17)
    at maybeClose (child_process.js:756:16)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:823:5)
```

please help me with this error
i really like to bulid hybrid apps with my web knowledge
thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this

Go to this directory

```
C:\Users\Mohammad\.cordova\lib\npm_cache\cordova-android\3.6.4\package\framework
```

Edit `project.properties` file. Change `target` to `19`.

```
# This file is automatically generated by Android Tools.
# Do not modify this file -- YOUR CHANGES WILL BE ERASED!
#
# This file must be checked in Version Control Systems.
#
# To customize properties used by the Ant build system use,
# "ant.properties", and override values to adapt the script to your
# project structure.

# Indicates whether an apk should be generated for each density.
split.density=false
# Project target.
target=android-19
apk-configurations=
renderscript.opt.level=O0
android.library=true
```

Restart your terminal.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have **SDK correctly installed** on you computer. (Path or SDK update)

It's **write** on your error log : You may not have the required environment or OS to build this project

Comment: What another question do you have ?

Answer (score -2):

you just need to install ant

```
sudo apt-get install ant
```

then do the same as before,its work correctly